# Android Material Design with NavigationDrawer and BackButton

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a toolbar with the "back button" on the left side and a button to to open the navigation drawer fragment on the right side. Now, if I click on the button on the right side and then on the back button on the left side, the app crashed and said : "No drawer view found with gravity LEFT". Yeah the fragment is on the right side and the question is how can I avoid this? Here is my code:

in OnCreate:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbarTutorial);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in onOptionsItemSelected:

```
   if (id == R.id.editInformations) {
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new ActionBarDrawerToggle(ProfileActivity.this,
                    drawerLayout, toolbarTutorial, R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    mSlideState = false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    mSlideState = true;
                }
            });
            clickEventSlide();
        }
```

and the clickEventSlide method:

```
public void clickEventSlide(){
        if(mSlideState){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
        }else{
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
        }}
```

Comment: possibly in onOptionItemSelected method override action for home button i.e `android.R.id.home`

Comment: yeah thanks fo replying but I already done this:
if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }